# Ruby db Migrate - unknown error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have just set up ruby in Aptana studio and am getting the following error when trying to migrate the db. I am a complete noob. Anyone have any idea as to where I need to be looking first? 
thanks.

```
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
>rake db:migrate --trace
(in C:/Users/7/My Documents/Aptana Studio Workspace/testing)
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:migrate
rake aborted!
unknown error
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/dl/import.rb:29:in `initialize'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/dl/import.rb:29:in `dlopen'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/dl/import.rb:29:in `dlload'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/dl/import.rb:27:in `each'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/dl/import.rb:27:in `dlload'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.1-x86-mswin32/lib/sqlite3/driver/dl/api.rb:63
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.1-x86-mswin32/lib/sqlite3/driver/dl/driver.rb:33
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.1-x86-mswin32/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:643:in `load_driver'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.1-x86-mswin32/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:641:in `each'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.1-x86-mswin32/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:641:in `load_driver'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.1-x86-mswin32/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:107:in `initialize'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:13:in `new'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:13:in `sqlite3_connection'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in `send'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in `new_connection'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:245:in `checkout_new_connection'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:188:in `checkout'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `loop'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `checkout'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:183:in `checkout'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:98:in `connection'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:326:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:121:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:113:in `connection'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:429:in `initialize'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:394:in `new'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:394:in `up'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `migrate'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/tasks/databases.rake:111
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:617:in `call'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:617:in `execute'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:612:in `each'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:612:in `execute'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:578:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:571:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:564:in `invoke'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:2027:in `invoke_task'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:2005:in `top_level'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:2005:in `each'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:2005:in `top_level'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:2044:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:1999:in `top_level'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:1977:in `run'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:2044:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:1974:in `run'
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/bin/rake:31
C:/ruby/bin/rake:19:in `load'
C:/ruby/bin/rake:19
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the sqlite dll is not installed properly.

Perhaps this will help: http://domhackers.blogspot.com/2008/09/sqlite3-ruby-gem-on-windows.html